# How to import VC++ project into MS Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

How do you import an existing VC++ library project (E.G. myVisualStudio2010project.vcxproj) into MS Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8?.

If you try to simply include it in your solution you get this error:

**Project 'myVisualStudio2010proj' could not be loaded because this version of Visual Studio only supports Metro style app, native desktop library (dll), and static library (lib) projects.**

The project I am working with is fairly complex and I am having issues with trying to recreate it within the new IDE.  Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2012 RC Express SKUs do not support desktop app development.  You will need to install the Ultimate SKU, which can be downloaded from [the Visual Studio web page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads).

When Visual Studio 2012 RTMs ([in August](https://twitter.com/jlzander/status/222895124739391488)), there will be a [Visual Studio Express 2012  for Windows Desktop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/08/visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop.aspx) that will support desktop app development.

Comment: Okay, your answer led me to the issue. I had the project set as .exe and changing it to .lib allowed me to include the project. Thanks!